# Overriding attribute in Python

Tags: python, overriding

I have this code:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = "name in B"
    
    def printName(self):
        print(self._name)

class D(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._name = "name in D"

o = D()
print(o._name)
o.printName()
```

Result:

> name in D
>
> name in D

I can override a "private" attribute in B (and this is a problem), so if I want to use class B I must know its private attribute to avoid this issue. But I think that who uses a class nust not to know its private attribute beacuse OOP wants information hiding, further a programmer would be limited to choose the name of attribute in derived class.

Comment: This is what `__`-prefixed names are for, to avoid accidentally overriding a "private" attribute used by the parent.

Comment: But in this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/private-protected-attributes-in-python-demystified-once-and-for-all-9456d4e56414 I see that with __name the attribute change name in _B__name (_D__name) and I don't want that.

Comment: As long as you access the attribute in a method of the class, you can access `__name` directly. The mangling means that you have to use the "long" form as an escape hatch if you really want access to the attribute from outside the class.